# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains the invalid value

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, onsubmit

I have created html page with `form` `submit`. On submit i am calling ajax `post` request.
But throws a error

> Failed to load http://radius.a3techlabs.com/app/custom/verifyAccessOTP: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://radius.a3techlabs.com/app/custom/verifyAccessOTP',
      dataType: 'json',
      type:'post',
      headers: {
          "charset":"UTF-8",
          "accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
        },
      data:value,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);   
        alert(data.message);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {}.bind(this)
    });
```

Comment: The access control headers must be sent by the server in response to a CORS request, not by the originator request. PLEASE can you search google for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin header contains the invalid value site:stackoverflow.com".

Answer (score 2):

```
module.exports.cors = {
  allRoutes: false,
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
  headers: 'content-type'
};
```

changed

> allRoutes:true

```
module.exports.cors = {
  allRoutes: true,
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
  headers: 'content-type'
};
```

it works,